# How can I move some of the Kendo MVC grid column definitions inside an helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo MVC Grid which is becoming really big and complex. I'd like to know how I can move some of the column definitions inside an helper method within the view. I can't figure out the right syntax for my helper method below.

```
@(Html.Kendo()
.Grid<MyModel>()
.Name("documents")
.Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.AutoBind(false)
.DataSource(b => b.Ajax()
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id(o => o.Id);
    })
    .Read(a => a.Action("documents", "document")
)
.Columns(c =>
{

    c.Bound(m => m.Name)
        .Title(Resources.Document.Name);
    c.Bound(m => m.Description)
        .Title(Resources.Document.Description);

    ...

    if(ViewBag.CanViewEquipmentColumns) {
        CreateEquipmentColumns(c); // The helper method
    }

    ...

    c.Bound(m => m.Size)
        .Title(Resources.Document.Size);
})
)

// Here is the code that I can't get to work. How can I define this custom helper method here using the Razor view engine and Kendo Grid fluent API?
@{
    Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridBoundColumnBuilder<MyModel> CreateEquipmentColumns(Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridColumnFactory<MyModel> c)
    {
        c.Bound(m => m.Equipment)
            .Title(Resources.MaintenanceBooklet.Equipment);
        c.Bound(m => m.StartDate)
            .Title(Resources.MaintenanceBooklet.StartDate);
        c.Bound(m => m.EndDate)
            .Title(Resources.MaintenanceBooklet.EndDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about method within the view. You should make extension method, something like that:

```
public static void CreateEquipmentColumns<MyModel>(this GridColumnFactory<MyModel> factory, WebViewPage<YourViewModel> webViewPage)
{
      factory.Bound(m => m.Equipment)
            .Title(Resources.MaintenanceBooklet.Equipment);
}
```

And u can use it within the view:

```
Columns(c =>
{

    c.Bound(m => m.Name)
        .Title(Resources.Document.Name);
    c.Bound(m => m.Description)
        .Title(Resources.Document.Description);

    ...

    if(ViewBag.CanViewEquipmentColumns) {
        c.CreateEquipmentColumns(this); // The helper method
    }

    ...

    c.Bound(m => m.Size)
        .Title(Resources.Document.Size);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add extension method like this and you can avoid repeating code across solution.

```
    public static class KendoExtensions
    {
     public static GridBuilder<T> AddDefaultOptions<T>(this GridBuilder<T> builder) where T : mymodelClass // Your class here
            {
                return builder
                            .Columns(c =>
                            {
                                c.Bound(m => m.Equipment).Title(Resources.MaintenanceBooklet.Equipment);
                                c.Bound(m => m.StartDate).Title(Resources.MaintenanceBooklet.StartDate);
                                c.Bound(m => m.EndDate).Title(Resources.MaintenanceBooklet.EndDate);
                            });

            }

    }
```

**View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Mydata)
                  .Name("mygrid")
                  .AddDefaultOptions()

)
```